# imacros firefox addon clicking button "Ok" if "Yes" not available?

Tags: firefox-addon, if-statement, imacros

I'm using imacros for doing repeated actions on some webpages.
I want to select attrib:Yes  if not "Yes" found on page select attrib:Ok

simple if else check.. how to do in imacros?

Comment: Might be better suited to superuser